# Change propagation among connections

Tags: postgresql

If I update a table using one connection and issue a query in another connection immediately after that, is there a chance that I can't see the changes even if it's extremely unlikely?

Answer (score 1):

If the first transaction has committed and the second transaction started after the first one committed (more accurately, it obtained its snapshot after the first one committed), then everything that the first transaction wrote will be visible to the second one.